# Change Navbar Color on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar cannot change color on scroll, i am already using this script. please help me

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function() { 
                if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) { 
                    $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "#f8f8f8"); 
                } else {
                $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "transparent");
            }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

i am using bootstrap

Comment: Can you also add your html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this works, you have to use `scrollTop()` to get `vertical scrollbar position` and accordingly made changes in your selected div i.e. over-here is `.navbar`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).on("scroll",function(){
   var wn = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(wn > 120){
     $(".navbar").css("background","rgba(255,0,0,1)");
    }
    else{
     $(".navbar").css("background","rgba(1,1,1,1)");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  height:1600px;
}
.navbar{
  background:rgba(1,1,1,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: it''s didn't work too. i'm using rgb color to make navbar color transparent

Comment: @Ryan It's you who needs to change the navbar color according to your plans I have just added example color from black to red and then back to black, change that value as you want.

Comment: it's didn't work too. are you using teamviewer? i can't solved this. please help me

Comment: @Ryan this is the solution and even you haven't provided your html, what issue you are facing I have provided you solution just replace your navbar class and css properties as you have planned for your project.

Comment: Okay. Thank's. i already solved this. the problem is in my css class

Comment: That's great @Ryan Welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am just curious on why arent you using affix that already comes with bootstrap? 
Here is the link :
http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp

in your case change add this line for your nav tag

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="(scroll value)" >
```

and css

```
.affix.navbar{
 background-color: color-you-prefer;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `css class` for color:

```
.anycolor {
    background-color: #f8f8f8";
}
```

and do that with this code :

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
    $('.navigation').addClass( "anycolor");
}
else {
    $('.navigation').removeClass("anycolor");
}
```