# Change link color on scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

I have this menu:

```
<div id = "menu" > 


    <a href = "index.html"> <img src = "images/logo.png" style = "padding-left: 5%; padding-top: 1%;"> </a>

    <ul id = "lista">
    <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "aboutus.html"> <padding left> SOBRE O INSTITUTO </a></li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "pessoas.html"> PESSOAS</a> </li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "universidadefour.html"> UNIVERSIDADE FOUR </a> 
            <ul>
                 <a href = "programaprolider.html"> <li> PROGRAMA PROLÍDER </li> </a> 
                 <a href = "universidadefour.html#escolapolitica"> <li> ESCOLA DE POLÍTICA </li> </a> 
                 <a href = "universidadefour.html#escolaempreendedorismo"> <li> ESCOLA DE EMPREENDEDORISMO </li> </a> 
            </ul> </li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "comunidadefour.html"> <padding left> COMUNIDADE FOUR </a>
            <ul>
                 <a href = "comunidadefour.html"> <li> A COMUNIDADE FOUR</li> </a>
                 <a href = "comunidade.html"> <li> FELLOWS </li> </a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "foursummit.html"> FOUR SUMMIT </a> </li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "trabalheconosco.html"> VAGAS ABERTAS</a> </li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "en-index.html"> EN </a> <span style = "color: white;"> |</span> <a href = "index.html"> BR </a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And these are the CSS specifications for the color of the links:

```
#menu ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4px 15px 4px 15px;
    color: white;
}
```

This menu doesn't have any specified background color. However, after the user scrolls around the page, it changes:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}
```

I want to do the same thing with this menu's link colors. How can I do it, change the links colors from white to #333333?

Thanks!

Comment: use `document.querySelector()` to select the <a> inside <li>

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367858/link-change-color-on-scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `document.querySelectorAll()` to select the  elements with the specified selector. [Learn More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Inside your function, within the `if(){}` block,

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("#lista a"); // selects all <a> inside #lista
links.forEach((link)=>link.style.color = "#333333"); // loop through each link and change the color
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getElementsByTagName() to select elements with specified tag and then change color of link one by one.

```
if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {    
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); //Select all <a> tags
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        y[i].style.color = "#333333"; //Loop through links array and change the link color
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats a great idea however there are more links in the same page that are not supposed to change when scrolling. Is there a way to filter these only these <a> tags?

Comment: @mr_leal if you want to get links in 'ul element' with' id lista', then you can filter by replacing as: `var y=document.getElementbyID("lista"). getElementsByTagName("a");` Also, you can change value of 'i' and condition in 'for loop' as per your convenience